# How to get a dataframe of past week Twitter tweet data indexed by minute using tweepy?

Tags: python, dataframe, twitter, tweepy

I'm using python 2 and I've searched extensively and looked at documentation to no avail. How to get a dataframe of past week Twitter tweet data indexed by minute using tweepy? I need a high frequency time series plot so I need per minute frequency of a search query being mentioned in a tweet for at least the past week. I've tried the following,

```
class listener(StreamListener):
def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        saveFile = open('DigitalCoins.csv','a')
        saveFile.write(data)
        saveFile.close()
        return(True)
    except BaseException as e:
        print('failed ondata,',str(e))
        time.sleep(5)
def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
word = 'hello world'
twitterStream.filter(track=[word],languages=['en'])
```

But unfortunately this just gives me data in real time and I can't just have my computer running to gather this data. Is there any way to retrieve the data in a window of a certain time in the past week? (Ex. 10/12/18 9:30 AM to 10/13/18 9:30 AM )